# Why does the for loop was executed at last in the typescript

Tags: for-loop, typescript, order-of-execution

According to the console that the for loop was executed in the final step,but i wrote it at the beginning of the ts file.why is this happening?

[typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmKsv.png)
[result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTEGC.png)

Comment: 1. You should add your code as text and marking it as `code` in the editor, having the code in an image (in another tab) doesn't make it easy to help you. 2. In your `for` loop you don't just print to the console, you use `setTimeout` to print to the console, so it will obviously happen in the end

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thank you so much!next time i'll put the code in editor